# Is there a standard way to convert a struct timeval into a struct timespec?

Tags: c, unix, posix, timeval, timespec

`struct timeval` represents and instant in time with two members, `tv_sec` (seconds) and `tv_usec` (microseconds). In this representation, `tv_usec` is not by itself an absolute time it is a sub second offset off of `tv_sec`.

`struct timespec` works the same way except that instead of microseconds it's offset (`tv_nsec`) is stored in nanosecond units.

The question is: Is there a standard way to convert between these two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at [this doc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html), I would think multiplying `tv_usec` by 1000 is sufficient to get `tv_nsec`.

More important, I suspect is the source of the different structures: they could be filled by different clocks.

Comment: Since tv_nsec is a sub second offset, what if the multiplication by 1000 results in a value greater than 1 billion... Wouldn't you then need to add 1 to tv_sec and then set tv_nsec to the amount over 1 billion?

Comment: No because `tv_usec`, being an offset in microseconds, is guaranteed to be smaller than 1 million, so multiplying it by 1000 gives a value less than 1 billion.

Comment: And if you want to go from a timespec to a timeval, you'd divide `tv_nsec` by 1000 to get `tv_usec` (possibly adding 500 first, to round up).

Answer (score 18):

In `sys/time.h` there are two macros that do what you want:

```
TIMEVAL_TO_TIMESPEC(X, Y)
```

and

```
TIMESPEC_TO_TIMEVAL(X, Y)
```

See the docs here: http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/TIMEVAL_TO_TIMESPEC.3.html

Comment: On Linux you may need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` before the `#include <sys/time.h>`, in order to get these macros.

Comment: Note TIMESPEC_TO_TIMEVAL truncates the tv_nsec value, which may not be desired. I.e. you may prefer to round up. This is required for example if passing a timeval to setitimer(), as if a timespec was truncated to zero, the timer would be cleared rather than being set to the min value (of a microsecond)